# Wiremock capture response body for later reuse

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm facing a particular use case while using Wiremock standalone API.

I would like to be able to reuse a response body generated by stubbing for a another request (stubbed as well) as a context model. The purpose is to store for a generated Id the entire response data, that would allow me to serve it again simply knowing the Id, in a get method particularly (where there is no request body). 
Is there a way while defining a stub of response to capture the generated response, in order to store it?

Or if you have other better idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case. I'm confused why you wouldn't want to regenerate the same response and make the request matching more generic to allow for the dynamic mapping of multiple input's to a single mapping.

Comment: For example you have a 1rst generated response from the request body information. The response generates an id that points to the request data.
Next request is a GET with no body but a url path corresponding to that generated ID. I want to return the same previews response, with modified data for instance...

Comment: To me it sounds like you want to have stateful behaviour. WireMock has some support for this. This is explained in the [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) depending upon your use case this may be suffcient. Have you had a look at it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by using an okhttp interceptor (which depends on your client solution).

In the interceptor, I store every response data (e.g.: a generated ID) and set them in every next request headers when it matches with part of the the response stored.

adding them to the request headers allows me to access them in a json template file for instance